# How to get TimeStamp data in hive when using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

```
val sql = "select time from table"
val data = sql(sql).map(_.getTimeStamp(0).toString)
```

In the hive table,time's type is timestamp.when i run this program,it throws NullPointerException.

```
val data = sql(sql).map(_.get(0).toString)
```

When I change to the above code,the same Exception be threw.

Is anyone can tell me how to get TimeStamp data in hive using Spark?
Tks.

Comment: can you print the schema of the DF( data) which is return from sql using `data.printSchema()`?

Comment: I check the table,some row is NULL...This is my fault.I should check data first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read data from Hive table you should use, HiveContext instead of SQLContext.

If you are using Spark 2.0, you can try the following.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql

val df = sql("select time from table")
df.select($"time").show()
```